# Parse log from first occurence to second

Tags: regex, sed

I have such logs:

```
#110110 styles for content editor
Merge branch 'develop' into 'master'
Merge branch 'develop' of gitlab:bitrix/sales into develop
Merge branch 'task-110397' into develop
fix img
Merge branch 'task_110110' into develop
#110110 add content editor styles
Merge branch 'develop' into 'master'
Merge branch 'develop' of gitlab:bitrix/sales into develop
Merge branch 'develop' into 'master'
```

I want to print only from first occurence of `'Merge branch 'develop'` into 'master'` to second.

I tried this:

```
sed -n -e '/\x27develop\x27\sinto\s\x27master\x27/,/\x27develop\x27\sinto\s\x27master\x27/ p'
```

But I couldn't insert occurencies in this code.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, please add expected output in code tags and let us know on same too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with GNU sed:

```
s="Merge branch 'develop' into 'master'"
sed -n "/$s/,/$s/{1,/$s/p}" file
```

Output:

```
Merge branch 'develop' into 'master'
Merge branch 'develop' of gitlab:bitrix/sales into develop
Merge branch 'task-110397' into develop
fix img
Merge branch 'task_110110' into develop
#110110 add content editor styles
Merge branch 'develop' into 'master'
```